# How to get a list of the name of every open window and place that into dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, win32gui

So I'm trying to use both win32gui and Pandas to get a dataframe (df) of windows that are open. Below is what I wrote. I end up with an error. How can I get one dataframe returned?

```
# info http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__EnumWindows_meth.html

import win32gui
import pandas as pd

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, dfx ):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ) and len(win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))>0 :
    idv = hex(hwnd)
    winv = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : idv , 'Window': winv}, index = ['0'])

    frames  = [dfx, df]
    dfx = pd.concat(frames)
    # print(dfx) 
    return dfx # Comment out this and it runs but not the result I want.

dfx= pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, dfx )
print(dfx)
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\s...\Python\List of windows.py", line 19, in <module>
    win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, dfx )
TypeError: an integer is required (got type DataFrame)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the key to getting the dataframe out of the function is to use a global variable. This variable must be state as global inside the function so there is not confusion and python does not consider it as local variable. Here is the code.

```
import win32gui
import pandas as pd

dfx = pd.DataFrame() 
i = 0

def winEnumHandler( hwnd, x ):
    global dfx, i

    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible( hwnd ) and len(win32gui.GetWindowText( hwnd ))>0 :
        idv = hex(hwnd)
        winv = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : idv , 'Window': winv}, index = [i])
        frames  = [dfx, df]
        dfx = pd.concat(frames)
        i += 1

win32gui.EnumWindows( winEnumHandler, i )
print(dfx)
```